# LateInitializationError: Field 'user' has not been initialized. Error in emulator even though it wrked fine before

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late User user;
  bool isloggedin = false;

  checkAuthentification() async {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user == null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("start");
      }
    });
  }
```

This is how I have initialized the user.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.checkAuthentification();
    this.getUser();
  }
```

I have used initstate but I still get the error.

```
 Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "${user.displayName}",
                      // "${user.email}",
                    style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I have used containers to display information about every user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By marking a variable as `late` you make an explicit promise to initialize that variable before you first try to read from it. The error you get is because your code fails to live up to that promise.

Specifically, the problem is that this is an asynchronous operation:

```
checkAuthentification() async {
  _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
    if (user == null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("start");
    }
  });
}
```

Calling `authStateChanges` takes time, so the code in the `listen` will only be run after a certain, undetermined amount of time. Worse: your `listen` then defines a `user` **parameter**, but it never sets the `users` field to any value.

The solution is to:

1. Mark the `user` field as a nullable variable.
2. Deal with the fact that the `user` field may be null in your `build` code.
3. Assign `user` when your `authStateChanges` stream fires.

In code that'd look something like this:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User? user; // 
  bool isloggedin = false;
```

```
checkAuthentification() async {
                                // 
  _auth.authStateChanges().listen((fuser) {
    user = fuser; // 
    if (user == null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("start");
    }
  });
}
```

```
Container(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Text(
      "${user?.displayName}", // 
      style:
      TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
  ),
),
```